# Interlaced Video Format 1080i (59.94)

Tags: full-hd

I have a video project and the format is for Broadcast TV and needs to be interlaced NOT progressive video.

High Definition File

- All High Definition content MUST be **1080i (59.94) format**
- All High Definition content should be 4:3 center-cut safe.
- Video Format: **1080i, 29.9 frames/sec (59.94 fields/sec)** HD File
  Format(s)
- File Format: XDCAM HD422: 4:2:2, at 50 Mbps MXF (OP1A, self
  contained)
- Video Codec: MPEG-2 Long GOP, Sony XDCAM compliant
- Field Order: Upper Field first
- Audio Format: 48 KHz sample rate, uncompressed
- Operating Level: Peak program levels at -12 to -8dBfs, nominal
  -10dBfs

I have never received / edited OR built / rendered out a 1080i (59.94) video before, always digital / progressive(.mp4 ).

I plan on using Adobe Premiere for any editing of the uncompressed footage and then for motion graphics / animation using After Effects.

My question is, how can I keep the format consistent, interlaced fields, across different applications and also what output format should be used for the final video / deliverables.

Can I apply my editing and motion graphics like normal with progressive, but @ 60 frames/sec, then at the very end export a rendered video that is 1080i?

Comment: About the output format, the spec you listed has it: MXF OP-1A XDCAMHD 4:2:2 at 50 Mbps. Note that this station hasn't updated their audio spec since the CALM Act went into effect. More important than the peak level they specified, make sure your audio hits a loudness target of -24 LKFS.

Comment: @ Michael Thanks for this information. All these varying formats are new to me and it is difficult to understand from the specifications which are describing what the video should be shot at, the raw footage which I will not have control over, and what is specifying the final output video needed. I will look inside Premiere for the MXF export option and see if I need to download a special codec.

Comment: No special codec is needed. Premiere has XDCAM HD presets already. XDCAM HD is just specific settings of MPEG-2. If you are submitting a final product like a commercial, a station's spec will never specify the shooting and production specs, only the specs for what they expect to receive.

Comment: @Michael good to know. Could you speak to what I asked Coin in the answer below. As far as my workflow I am hoping to work exclusively inside AE then export an uncompressed AVI / Quicktime. Bring that into PPro and export with the correct codec and Frame Blending as Coin recommended in his answer. When working inside AE should it be 60 f/s to give the 1080i the highest possible resolution when converted into interlaced video, giving each even / odd frames 30 f/s, still confused on this aspect.

Comment: I don't know enough about frame blending to answer your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to replicate the precise "look" of 59.94, even with special plugins. This, due to the fact that interlaced is in many ways like:

Double Frame Rate - Half Resolution.

Think of 59.94i at 1080 really as 119.88 at 540p.

Interlaced lines are scanned odd lines first, then even. So you technically have a first set of lines which are actually one frame, with the other set of lines missing. These lines are then displayed back to the viewer odd/even//odd/even//odd/even etc.

That said, you get smoother motion with i vs p. You are able to achieve better slow motion in post production with i vs p, however, p, is of course the preferred format to most. A single frame being a single frame.

*NOW THAT SAID...*

**Looks aside,** in order to output your video from PPro, all you will simply want to do is import the footage material in (original); right mouse click; new sequence from clip; make any edits/trims, etc.

It is really unnecessary to make any additional adjustments from the timeline in Premiere, because what you ultimately want to do is use **Frame Blending** when you export.

After you've made any adjustments, go to export, choose the format you need; 59.94i, whatever codecs they are requiring, many are already built in; others may need to be downloaded.

Ensure you turn on Frame Blending, IF your source material is progressive.

Frame Blending will force interpolation of the frames during the rendering of your new video outputs, using two side by side discreet progressive frames to create a new "quasi" interlaced frames, twice as many frames as your progressive source at the correct frame rate.

It isn't quite the same "look" wise as actual Interlaced source material; however, specification wise it should meet their needs; and to the average viewer most will not notice.

Do not however use Frame Blending if you are using Interlaced material. And do not double the effect by applying it to the clip in the timeline (which you can do by right clicking the clip; Under Frame Blending/Field Options); and then stack it with another Blend on export. Only one is necessary, and my recommendation is simply allow Adobe Media Encoder handle the p to i conversion.

Lastly, if you have material at lower resolution, AME will be upscaling it to get to 1080. If so, you can use the Use Maximum Render Quality Checkbox at the bottom of the export panel window.

Be advised this will likely increase your rendering time by multiple fold.

In regards to the audio; they have peaking requirements. You will need to apply a Dynamics and/or Limiter filter in the Audio Mixer Window Filter Dropdown. Limit to the specifications they have stated.

In regards to center safe, if you're given material that isn't center safe, you're going to need to talk with them about that, as you'll have to do a push in and do manual pan and scan using the motion filter, adjusting the frame position on the canvas to get it to 4:3 safe.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, this really helps! I will be receiving the raw footage and storyboard either tomorrow or the next day. My hope is the source video is shot at the higher quality, so no need to be upscaled and I believe it will be interlaced but can't be sure at this time.

Comment: Based on the complexity of the storyboard / animation I would rather work inside After Effects, even for the editing / trims combined with Title work etc. But, I want to be clear. If I do all my work within AE and then export as an uncompressed AVI / Quicktime / High quality mp4 (slight compression) can I then bring in the AE footage into Premiere and export it as 1080i, with Frame Blending?